# Unable to open vim from command line in 16.04lts Server

Tags: server

Unable to open vim from command line in Ubuntu 16.04lts server.

```
$vim config.properties
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim:
line    1:
E492: Not an editor command: <be><98>
line    2:
E492: Not an editor command: ^H^K<9a>
line    3:
E492: Not an editor command: <d2>y^V8^Z<dd>^X^C<db>X^B<e1>^X
line    4:
E492: Not an editor command: <99>
line    5:
E492: Not an editor command: <a1>^T
line    6:
E492: Not an editor command: ^D^Q^B^C^Z^K
```

Comment: Your file `/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim` is badly broken. I would say reinstall Vim, but you should first investigate how did a file under `/usr/share` get mangled up.

Answer (score 2):

As [AlexP states](/questions/857739/unable-to-open-vim-from-command-line-in-16-04lts-server#comment1321600_857739), your `/usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim` is completely mangled for some reason. The easiest way to restore it is to reinstall its source package.

To find the source package:

```
$ dpkg-query -S /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
vim-runtime: /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
```

To reinstall it:

```
sudo apt install --reinstall vim-runtime
```

---

In the future, if you want to detect corrupted packages early please refer to [Find (and reinstall) packages with corrupted files (without breaking anything)](/q/57682/175814).

Comment: I got this error when trying run the command below:
 dpkg-query -S /usr/share/vim/vim74/filetype.vim
dpkg-query: error: too-long line or missing newline in '/var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File'

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? Especially file or program output [listings](/editing-help#code) (with the help of the `{}` button in the editor toolbar) will be much more readable there since multi-line listings aren't shoved into a single line. Also, what's the output of `file /var/lib/dpkg/triggers/File`? Thanks.

Comment: If it's a text file could you please upload it to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and include a link to it in your question?

Comment: will do in the future. The contents of the file is binary not text.

Comment: Thinking more about it that issue actually deserves its own question since it's independent of this one. Could you please open a new question with all the information in your above comments? Send me link to it here if you want me to look at it. :-)